# Trigger to update Lead Owner in Custom Call Object

Tags: trigger, triggercontext

I have made a trigger on Custom Call Object to change the lead ownership of the queue to the Current User as we do not want the Sales Agent to have the owner the leads before they Qualify the leads as Enrolled Confirmed, this has been made after integration of Hermes Cloud integration for the Dialer.

```
trigger vhccall on vhc__call__c (after insert) {
    list<lead> leadsToUpdate = new list<lead>();
    set<String> setValues = new set<String>();
        for(Call_lead_Owner__c lo : Call_lead_Owner__c.getAll().Values())
            setValues.add(lo.item_Name__c);

        for(vhc__Call__c call: trigger.new){
            if(setValues.contains(Call.Call_Status_Item_Name__c) && call.Lead_Owner__c != UserInfo.getUserId())
                leadsToUpdate.add(new lead(Id = call.vhc__Lead__c, OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId()));
        }

       if(!leadsToUpdate.isEmpty())
           update leadsToUpdate;
       }
```

But this is not updating the lead owner. Please any suggestions

Comment: Are you getting any error or it just not updating the record when you are checking it manually?

Comment: @Jawad Ahmed  Put some debug statements in there and create a log.  Check to make sure the values you are receiving are the ones you expect.